# Create Life Event with Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

Through the Facebook UI a user can create a so called "Life Event" on his timeline (which is actually an Open Graph activity) and add specific attributes to this activity, for example:

Started a new Job; attributes: employer, position, location, time, story

The Facebook [Build-in Action Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/) and the [Build-in Object Types](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/) do not include anything that would result in an Activity like the one above. So my question is: Is it posible to create such "Life Events" with the Open Graph API, which would look similar to those created through the Facebook UI, without defining my own action and object types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to create Life Events for users. Though it is possible for pages:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/life-event

Comment: Is it possible to create life event for user also? I think that graph api is providing this for page only. Not for user.

Comment: @AkbariDipali You're right. The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference) describe the Graph API Root Node _Life Event_ as _Page milestone information_. Thanks for the hint!